# Upgrade to Facebook's new SDK and keep logged in users

Tags: android, facebook, authentication, access-token

When upgrading to Facebook's new APIs on Android existing users get logged-out and need to log-in again.

Answer (score 0):

Solution is:

```
FacebookSdk.setLegacyTokenUpgradeSupported(true);
FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(this);
```

See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/current/class/FacebookSdk/#setLegacyTokenUpgradeSupported

Comment: Don't forget you should also set the application id before you call initialize

FacebookSdk.setApplicationId(fbAppId);
FacebookSdk.setLegacyTokenUpgradeSupported(true);
FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(this);